# How do I change the space for specific cells in longtable

Tags: tables, spacing, longtable, cellspace

Please could you help me with the following code (below)?

The last column of the text for the first study has a long text and I would like to squeeze it within the cell space or perhaps space the cells for that specific study.

The problem is: I would like to make sure that the spacing only applies to a specific cell with long text. I have a list of other studies that do not require the cell spacing of the text to be reduced or the cells to be expanded in terms of spacing.

The more general your code, the better will be for me (ie, if latex is able to automatically adjust everything or squeeze the text in a nice way)

Many thanks in advance for your help

Xavier

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lscape} 
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[style=nejm,backend=biber, maxbibnames=99, minnames=3, maxnames=20, terseinits=true, giveninits=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=35mm, right=25mm,left=25mm, bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{ltablex,booktabs}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\small
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.70}%
\begin{longtable}{
>{\centering\hspace{0pt}}m{0.10\linewidth}
>{\centering\hspace{0pt}}m{0.10\linewidth}
>{\centering\hspace{0pt}}m{0.09\linewidth}
>{\centering\hspace{0pt}}m{0.106\linewidth}
>{\centering\hspace{0pt}}m{0.096\linewidth}
>{\centering\hspace{0pt}}m{0.15\linewidth}
>{\centering\hspace{0pt}}m{0.15\linewidth}
>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{0.15\linewidth}
} 

\cline{1-8}

\textbf{Reference} & \textbf{HRQoL instruments} & \textbf{HRQoL domain} & \textbf{Assessment timepoints} & \textbf{HRQoL estimates} & \textbf{Investigational estimates} & \textbf{Reference estimates} & \textbf{Comparison between groups} \\

\cline{1-8}

    \multirow{2}{\hsize}{\centering author, date} & \multirow{2}{\hsize}{\centering EORTC QLQ C-30} & \multirow{2}{\hsize}{\centering Global} & Baseline & \multirow{2}{\hsize}{\centering Mean(SD) [N]} & 66.7 (18.4) [NR] & 58 (23) [NR] & \multirow{2}{\hsize}{\centering Time adjusted difference (95\%CI): -0.40 (-3.5,2.7), p>0.05 despite higher \% of AEs in investigational arm} \\
\cmidrule{4-4}\cmidrule{6-7}          &       &       & \footnotesize End of treatment &       & 51.1 (22.3) [NR] & 52.2 (25.9) [NR] &  \\
\cmidrule{2-4}\cmidrule{6-8}          & \multirow{2}{\hsize}{\centering EQ-5D} & \multirow{2}{\hsize}{\centering Utility index} & Baseline &       & 0.84 (0.19) [NR] & 0.75 (0.23) [NR] & \multirow{2}{\hsize}{\centering Time adjusted difference (95\%CI): 0 (-0.1, 0), p>0.05 despite higher \% of AEs  in investigational arm} \\
\cmidrule{4-4}\cmidrule{6-7}          &       &       & \footnotesize End of treatment &       & 0.57 (0.40) [NR] & 0.57 (0.39) [NR] &  \\
\cmidrule{3-4}\cmidrule{6-8}          &       & \multirow{2}{\hsize}{\centering Global} & Baseline &       & 73.4 (17.3) [NR] & 71.4 (17.4) [NR] & \multirow{2}{\hsize}{\centering Time adjusted difference (95\%CI): -1.2 (-4, 1.7), p>0.05 despite higher \% of AEs  in investigational arm} \\
\cmidrule{4-4}\cmidrule{6-7}          &       &       & \footnotesize End of treatment &       & 61.5 (21.4) [NR] & 62.6 (22.3) [NR] &  \\
    \midrule

    \multirow{2}{\hsize}{\centering autor2, date} & \multirow{2}{\hsize}{\centering EORTC QLQ C-30} & \multirow{9}{\hsize}{\centering Global} & Baseline & \multirow{2}{\hsize}{\centering Mean (95\%CI) [N]} & 74.4(73.1,75.6) [796] & 74.8(73.6,76) [794] & \multirow{2}{\hsize}{\centering Significant differences between treatments at 3-6 months (p<0.05) favouring investigational group} \\
\cmidrule{4-4}\cmidrule{6-7}     &  &  & 1 month &  & 70.3(68.9,71.7) [719] & 69.2(67.6,70.8) [677] &  \\
\cmidrule{4-4}\cmidrule{6-7}     &  &  & 2 months &  & 65.8(64.3,67.3) [660] & 64.5(62.9,66.1) [664] &  \\
\cmidrule{4-4}\cmidrule{6-7}     &  &  & 3 months &  & 65.8(63.9,67.6) [456] & 64.4(62.8,66) [597] &  \\
\cmidrule{4-4}\cmidrule{6-7}     &  &  & 4 months &  & 75.2(73.8,76.6) [543] & 65.5(63.9,67.1) [554] &  \\
\cmidrule{4-4}\cmidrule{6-7}     &  &  & 5 months &  & 77.5(76.1,78.9) [522] & 66(64.4,67.6) [504] &  \\
\cmidrule{4-4}\cmidrule{6-7}     &  &  & 6 months &  & 77.7(76.4,79.1) [509] & 65.5(63,68) [204] &  \\
\cmidrule{4-4}\cmidrule{6-7}     
    \midrule


\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The short answer is: use `\multicolumn{1}...` to change the format of a single cell.  You can also use `\parbox` as an entry.

Comment: Please can you edit my code and show me how would I do it? Thanks

Comment: It is difficult to tell from context what your are trying to do.  Much of the code has no function.  One thing I would suggest is to set `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{\dimexpr 0.058\linewidth/16}` to reduce the total width to \linewidth.

Comment: sorry, I do not understand, could you edit my code so I understand. I want to make sure that the text "Time adjusted difference (95\%CI): -1.2 (-4, 1.7), p>0.05 despite higher \% of AEs  in investigational arm" fits within the 2 rows that are lead by "Baseline" and "End of treatment"

Comment: No but I can compute the width needed.

Answer (score 2):

As promising solution seems to be use of the `tabularray` package. Its solution for multi row cells automatically increase cells height for amount that  text doesn't protrude to cell below it.

As example its use let be first part of table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,
            %width=150mm,
            hmargin=25mm,
            vmargin={25mm, 35mm},
            bindingoffset=6mm
            ]{geometry}

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}
    \small
\begin{longtblr}[caption = {The Caption}]%
                {hlines, vlines,
                 colspec={l X[0.9, c] X[0.9, c]  X[1.1, c] *{3}{X[1, c]} X[2, c] },
                 colsep =2pt,
                 rowhead = 1,
                 row{1} = {font=\bfseries\small},
                 }
%%%%    table body
Reference       & HRQoL instruments         & HRQoL domain          & Assessment time points &
HRQoL estimates & Investigational estimates & Reference estimates   & Comparison between groups \\
%
\SetCell[r=6]{h} author, date    
                & EORTC QLQ         & \SetCell[r=2]{h} Global
                                                        & Baseline  &
\SetCell[r=6]{h} Mean(SD) [N]    
                & 66.7 (18.4) [NR]  & 58 (23) [NR]      & \SetCell[r=2]{m} Time adjusted difference (95\%CI):
                                                          -0.40 (-3.5,2.7), p>0.05 despite higher \% of AEs in investigational arm
                                                        \\
                &  C-30             &                   & End of treatment &
                & 51.1 (22.3) [NR]  & 52.2 (25.9) [NR]  &                       \\
%
                & \SetCell[r=4]{h} EQ-5D             
                                    & \SetCell[r=2]{h} Utility index     
                                                        & Baseline          &
                & 0.84 (0.19) [NR]  & 0.75 (0.23) [NR]  & \SetCell[r=2]{h} Time adjusted difference (95\%CI):
                                                          0 (-0.1, 0), p>0.05 despite higher \% of AEs  in                                                           investigational arm   \\
%
                &                   &                   & End of treatment  &       
                & 0.57 (0.40) [NR]  & 0.57 (0.39) [NR]  &                       \\

                &                   & \SetCell[r=2]{h} Global            
                                                        & Baseline          &       
                & 73.4 (17.3) [NR]  & 71.4 (17.4) [NR]  & \SetCell[r=2]{h} Time adjusted difference (95\%CI): 
                                                          -1.2 (-4, 1.7), p>0.05 despite higher \% of AEs  in investigational arm   \\
                &                   &                   & End of treatment &      
                & 61.5 (21.4) [NR]  & 62.6 (22.3) [NR]  &                       \\
\end{longtblr}
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you not like vertical lines, remove option `vlines` from table preamble.

Comment: sorry but your code does not work. I also need the code to work in the context of longtable

Comment: @Xavier, my code work for sure. And it is prepared to write  long tables. BTW, "doesn't work" is not usable information. Please provide errors, which you get at compilation. Do you have installed `tabularray` package?

Comment: Thank you. There is something simple about your code which might be beneficial. I am using overleaf to run my code, This is the error I get "LaTeX Error: File `tabularray.sty' not found.". However, I did include the command "\usepackage{tabularray}" so I do not undersand why it does not work.

Comment: @Xavier, Overleaf has not installed `tabularray` package yet, You need to add it yourself.

Comment: how do I do it?

Comment: @Xavier, ask Overleaf support. I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: Is there a way the code can be done without tabularray?

Comment: @Xavier, of course, but codes are less elegant and simple. See other answers.

Comment: @Xavier, of course, but codes are less elegant and simple. See other answers. Simpler is search here for tag ˙Overleaf` and see, if there are instruction, how to add some package to Overleaf, or ask its support. People there are very kind and helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This computes the width needed to fit a line of text into two lines.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\twolinewidth}[1]{% #1 = text to put into two lines
  \sbox0{#1}% measure width
  \dimen0=0.5\wd0
  \loop\sbox0{\parbox{\dimen0}{#1}}% iterate over small increments
    \dimen1=\dimexpr \ht0+\dp0\relax
    \ifdim\dimen1>2\baselineskip\relax
    \advance\dimen0 by 1pt
  \repeat
  \edef\twolineresult{\the\dimen0}}
  
\begin{document}
  \twolinewidth{Time adjusted difference (95\%CI): -1.2 (-4, 1.7), p>0.05 despite higher \% of AEs in investigational arm}%
  \twolineresult\\
  \rule{\twolineresult}{1pt}\\
  \parbox{\twolineresult}{Time adjusted difference (95\%CI): -1.2 (-4, 1.7), p>0.05 despite higher \% of AEs in investigational arm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: apologies but I do not understand how to adapt your code to my code. I am a beginner in Latex and I am struggling to understand what to do. Please could you help me with the actual code I presented which is in the context of longtable? Many thanks. Xavier

Comment: You don't have to incorporate this into your code, just run it.  It tells you how wide to make a column to fit the text you gave into two lines.

Comment: I get the impression you really don't understand what the code you are using does (which is understandable).  For example, if you were to throw out all the \hspace{0pt}, nothing would change.